# Else If Statement error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, if-statement

```
Protected Sub s1click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles s1.Click
        If s1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/available_seat_img.gif" Then
            s1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/selected_seat_img.gif"
            Button1.Enabled = True
            TextBox1.Text = s1.ID.ToString() + ","
        ElseIf s1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/selected_seat_img.gif" Then
            '   Button1.Enabled = False
            s1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/available_seat_img.gif"
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("s1", "")
        End If
    End Sub
```

when i run this code ... the second Elseif condition will not work...
whats the problem with this code snippet ...

Comment: Please add more information. And try step by step debugging. Maybe s1.imageurl is not set to selected_seat_img.gif?

Comment: you can use `Select Case s1.ImageUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to see what the value is set to at the start of the function (with a `MessageBox` or something similar). It may not be what you expect.

If `s1.ImageUrl` *is* set to `"~/Images/selected_seat_img.gif"`, then it should work fine.